# I want to validate the string number.anycapitalalphabet

Tags: shell

I have a shell script in which i have to validate strings that consist of any uppercase alphabetic characters using regular expression.

Example : `123456.A` or `43544.Z`

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it or explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
... | sed "s/^\([0-9]*\.[A-Z]\)$/\1 --> OK/g"
```

example :

```
echo "123456.A 43544.Z toto001.9s" | tr ' ' '\n' | sed "s/^\([0-9]*\.[A-Z]\)$/\1 --> OK/g"

#123456.A --> OK
#43544.Z --> OK
#toto001.9s
```